# upload file to sftp from jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, sftp

My task is automate uploading file to sftp server by using Jenkins CI.
My permissions is very limited and I have no access to sftp server via ssh.
I have tried to use  sftp bash command but have a problem with automation input password (expect can not be installed)
Curl also have problems :

```
curl --insecure  -vvv -T filename.xml -u user:password sftp://server.com:XXXX
* About to connect() to server.com port XXXX (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx... connected
* Connected to server.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port XXXX (#0)
* SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
* Using ssh public key file /home1/user/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
* Using ssh private key file /home1/user/.ssh/id_dsa
* SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file
* Initialized password authentication
* Authentication complete
* Upload failed: Permission denied (3/-31)

Connection #0 to host server.com left intact

curl: (9) Upload failed: Permission denied (3/-31)
* Closing connection #0
```

Can you help me to find another way or resolve my problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I think this ticket is not actual now. I have found enother way for uploading, file which I want to upload is generated by use of java, I used java for upload this file too.
But anyway thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'My permissions is very limited and I have no access to sftp server
>   via ssh.'

If you can't access the server via SSH, any SSH based authentication system isn't going to work.   Your public key can't be opened, so check that it's the correct file path to the public key and that it's the right type of key.  Should start with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and end with the same comment.